# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_DB_mysql_driver' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to install a script but when I install it, I get this error,

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_DB_mysql_driver' not found in /home/portailm/public_html/cariston.com/system/database/DB.php:144

```
// Instantiate the DB adapter
    $driver = 'CI_DB_'.$params['dbdriver'].'_driver';
    $DB = new $driver($params);

    if ($DB->autoinit == TRUE)
    {
        $DB->initialize();
    }

    if (isset($params['stricton']) && $params['stricton'] == TRUE)
    {
        $DB->query('SET SESSION sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"');
    }

    return $DB;
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have mysql driver, try to change default driver to mysqli in `application/config/database.php`:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
```